# How to return from multiple classes c#

Tags: c#, rest

I'm unsure how to word the title and have searched the best I could, but really still not sure how to handle this.

I need to create a return that looks like:

> [
>   {
>   "Name" : "First|Last" ,
>   "Id" : 1 ,
>   "Allowed" : true ,
>   "date" : "datestring" ,
>   "EndTime" : "11:00 AM" ,
>   "Time" : "10:00"
>   "Settings" : [
>   {
>   "id" : 1,
>   "name" : "TestName" ,
>   "maxValue" : 100
>   }

My code, obviously I can't do new settings inside of that, so how do I go about pushing that bit into the return? Or am I going about this completely wrong?

```
    public Information[] PMI(string Id)  
    {
        return new Information[]
        {
            new Information
            {
                Name = "First|Last",
                NameId = "1",
                Allowed = true,
                date = "Feb 1, 2018",
                EndTime = "1:00 PM",
                DateTime = "09:00"
            },
            new Settings
            {
                id = 1,
                name = "TestName",
                maxValue = "1000"
            }
        };
    }

public class Information
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool Allowed { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
    public string DateTime { get; set; }

}

public class Settings
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string maxValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want. You want to return a array of Information instances. Yet you only create a single one. And you also try to put a Settings instance into the array? You might be stuck in a XY problem. So go a few steps back and tell us what the problem is that you try to solve this way.

Comment: The provided json example is incomplete. It's unclear what you'd like to achieve

Comment: Yes, basically returning some objects. But I need to somehow return both within the same return. 

Perhaps there's a better method to the current madness, as I've just added the code from the single returns and tried to make it work.

Comment: @LeviTheOne 
I'm not sure what could be added after the edit to make it clear. I'm trying to return two array's from the objects in one method. Perhaps the method isn't proper, or a simpler way to do this.

Comment: Your class structure doesn't match the sample JSON. In your sample JSON, Settings is a property on your information class but you are creating them like unrelated objects (parent child Vs siblings)

Comment: @StackUser77288 Your JSON example is incomplete (missing closing brackets), but I assume that what you want to do is add an array of `Settings` as a property to `Information`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you need:

```
   public Information[] PMI(string Id)  
{
    return new Information[]
    {
        new Information
        {
            Name = "First|Last",
            NameId = "1",
            Allowed = true,
            date = "Feb 1, 2018",
            EndTime = "1:00 PM",
            DateTime = "09:00"
            Settings = new Settings
            {
                id = 1,
                name = "TestName",
                maxValue = "1000"
            }
        },

    };
}
```

---

```
public class Information
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool Allowed { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
    public string DateTime { get; set; }
    public Settings Settings {get; set;}
}

public class Settings
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string maxValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I get a cannot implicitly convert type from ParentClass [] to Information[] then.

Comment: If you cannot change what is receiving the information then you will need to nest the Settings class inside of Information

Comment: Thanks, I marked as correct because I chopped up the first bit.

What I came up with that works is what you edited to -- but the nesting you some reason need to settings = new settings { id="1", etc, etc}

Works perfectly now :) Thanks for understanding my vague-ish question.